# What should be the graph of $[y]=[\sin x]$?

Tags: graphing-functions

What should be the graph of $$[y]=[\sin x]?$$(here $[a]$ reffers to the floor function.)

In my opinion if we just consider the square bounded by $(0,0) ,(0,1),(\pi,0)$ and $(\pi,1)$ then any point inside the square will satisfy the equation as $[y]=0$ and so is $[\sin x]$.

But as I looked up to desmos the graph shows something else.It just covers the border and not the points inside the square.
Why is it so?
I am unable to upload the screenshot of the graph here.

Comment: Please have a look here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference also, what is the meaning of $[y]$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I think the OP is referring to the floor function.

Comment: @Shahab yes .I am referring to floor function.

Comment: great, please put that info in your question with the "edit" button

Comment: @Calvin Khor Thanks for the suggestion.I have edited my question.

Comment: Begin by plotting $y=\sin x$. Due to the RHS, only 3 cases can arise $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor = -1,0$ or (exceptionnaly) $1$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand that you're looking for the set of pairs 
$$ \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: [y] = [\sin x] \}$$
Since this is not in the form $"y=f(x)"$, its not a graph, but a more general collection of points. In this specific case, you end up with filled in regions of the graph paper.

For $0\le x<\pi/2$, $\sin x\in [0,1)$ so  $[\sin x]=0$. Then the set of points $y$ such that $[y] = 0$ is not a single point, but in fact a whole interval $[0,1)$.

The same is true for $\pi/2 < x \le \pi$, but at $x=\pi/2$, $[\sin \pi/2] = 1$, so then $y$ can take any value in $[1,2)$.

For the other half of the period, $\sin(x) \in [-1,0)$, and then $[\sin x] = -1$. In the end, you end up with a drawing something like:

```
     |        |
...[) (]    [) (]    ...
        (..)     (..)
```

Not sure what you put into Desmos, but [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b58kbyq4tq) is how I coaxed Desmos into plotting the correct thing:
[image]
I had to manually add certain features of the graph that I wanted to emphasize, but if you zoom in then my graph becomes "wrong".

Comment: I understand that is not a function as for one value of x there can be many values of y.But the graph of desmos shows just the border.I did not understand the drawing you posted at last.Maybe because I recieved it in a jumbled up format.

Comment: @NeelarghyaKundu I managed to force desmos to output what I wanted to see, but its a lot more complicated than just telling it $[y]=[\sin x]$ (see edit). Hopefully that justifies my ASCII art

Comment: Ok.Now I can see the result I wanted.I had simply typed floor(y)=floor (sin x).Can you give me an explanation why that is showing the wrong graph?

Comment: And why do you think that your graph is wrong when enlarged and seen?

Comment: Because I used a small parameter $\alpha$ to force desmos to not draw the region under the thin lines that stick out. If you zoom in around that line, you will see that actually, nothing at all is plotted to the left and right of the lines. But because of how fat a pixel is, the result looks OK at standard zoom.

Comment: Ok !Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NeelarghyaKundu you're welcome :)